# Pass bash variable when sshing

Tags: bash, ssh, parameter-passing

I'm having some issues with multiple people running an application that requires port forwarding. I'd like to generate a random port number, ssh to the application server while passing that random number, and `sed` replace the default port with this one in a few different scripts.

So is there any way I can pass a bash variable through ssh or alternatively is there a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: if you are just generating a random number, what is the difference between generating it locally vs on the machine into which you `ssh`d?

Comment: because it's a random number used as a port to forward when establishing the ssh connection as well as a port to forward from a docker container to this remote server (two-hop connection)

Comment: `ssh name@host "sed -i -e \"s/$myrandnumber/22/g\" file1 file2 file3"` works?

Comment: The files could be located at different locations so I was going to use some python code on the server (wherever it happens to be located), that when run would pull the value of the shell variable I hope to pass, then use it later on to  rewrite values in a file with a known relative path (but not known absolute path). I know its kind of confusing, maybe a different approach would be cleaner.

Comment: `ssh name@host "python myscript.py $myrandnumber"` ?

Comment: Sorry I didn't word that properly, the python code is bundled with the files without a known absolute path. So the python script knows the other files are in the same directory, but the directory itself could be anywhere. That's why after connecting to the server and navigating to the directory path (wherever it is) I wanted running the python script to pull a shell variable that I passed with ssh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know what you want to do with your variable, you can pass it to the remote host and run the commands on the same line:

```
ssh name@host "sed -i -e \"s/$myrandnumber/22/g\" file1 file2 file3"
```

`$myvar` will expand before the `ssh`ing happens, meaning it will be the value you set on the original machine, not the remote. You can make it a variable on the remote machine:

```
ssh name@host "export remotevar=$myrandnumber; bash -i"
```

But it'll only be available to the current session. If you just want the variable stored for some future date, then your best bet is writing to a file that will get sourced later, i.e.,

```
ssh name@host "echo \"myvar=$myrandnumber\" >> /etc/environment"
```

Comment: Thanks. I'd like to simply do what's on your first line, but the server I'm connecting to has two-factor authentication which might be why it won't connect when I try to add the variable.

Comment: Should have been more clear. The first line cannot do anything (edited). You can't make a global variable across multiple sessions without writing to file somewhere. The closest you could do is appending to `/etc/environment` so that all users on that machine will have that variable.

Comment: Strangely when I add "echo $test" to my ssh command it asks for two factor authentication, prints, then does not connect. I guess this might be a separate question.

Comment: That is expected behavior. It did connect. The connection is only up for the duration of the command. Once it runs out of commands in the `""`, it ends the connection and returns you to your local machine. That is why you cannot just send a variable over; you have to immediately know what to do with it or have it persist by writing it to file somewhere.

Comment: Ah ok. Can I write it over and then maintain connection?

Comment: No, but you can write to file and then reconnect. If you wrote to someplace that is sourced on login, like `.bashrc` or `/etc/environment`, you'll have that variable

Comment: Actually, you can maintain the connection by invoking a shell as a part of command passed to SSH, similar to the last example: `ssh name@host "export remotevar=$myvar; bash -i"`

Comment: @Austin Hey I was wrong, see the comment above this.